# Javascript code to alter the href of an anchor link to what the user is typing into an input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamically change the href of an achor link on the screen to what the user is typing into an input box. I have jquery loaded if necessary or can use raw javascript.

Extra note that may or may not be important: The div that contains the input box and the anchor link is itself dynamic (may or may not be on the screen depending on the user's actions) so I am going to use the 'live' function of jquery to run the code when the div box appears. This is necessary since I am using various posts to navigate through the website (it is for mobile web platforms).

Thanks for any help

Edit: Hey thanks for answers my question they are great and put me in the right direction but I have realised I didn't think through my question (sorry), what I want to actually do is append what they type onto the END of an existing href (it's a Get request to an api) So if they type 'example' it will add 'example' onto the href of 'www.apitest.com?variable='. It would be really helpful if you could tweak your example to do this. Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer (I accidentally asked a slightly different question to what I really needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know the structure of you page, so you need to replace $('input'), $('a') with selectors of input and anchor according to your page.

```
var apiUrl = 'www.apitest.com?variable=';
$('input').live('keyup', function(){
    $('a').attr('href', apiUrl+$(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the code it answers my question but I have realised I didn't think through my question, what I want to actually do is append what they type onto the END of an existing href (it's a Get request to an api) So if they type 'example' it will add 'example' onto the href of 'www.apitest.com?variable='. It would be really helpful if you could tweak your example to do this. Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way is just to store link to api somewhere and append user input to it. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks very much. Worked a treat.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="newAnchor" />
    <p><a href="" id="addAnchor">Show Link</a></p>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('#newAnchor').live('keyup', function(){
    var n = $(this).val();
    $('#addAnchor').attr('href','#' + n);  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Z39gt/

Hover over link at any time to see the change in the bottom bar.

**EDIT**

As per the comment, you should be able to place the new link you receive in a variable and reference it.

```
var link = 'http://www.apitest.com?variable=';

$('#newAnchor').live('keyup', function(){
    var n = $(this).val();
    $('#addAnchor').attr('href', link + n);  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Z39gt/3/

Comment: Hey thanks for the code it answers my question but I have realised I didn't think through my question, what I want to actually do is append what they type onto the END of an existing href (it's a Get request to an api) So if they type 'example' it will add 'example' onto the href of 'www.apitest.com?variable='. It would be really helpful if you could tweak your example to do this. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, @David.  See above.